# How to solve for the number of rotations for a spiral

Tags: calculus, polar-coordinates

I am trying to figure out how to solve for the amount of $n$ turns in a spiral when I have given the inner radius, the total length of the spiral, and the distance between each coil. The spiral is spinning outwards and the distance between each arm stays constant.  I tried using archimedes spiral equation and try to solve for $n$ however I keep getting stuck and unable to solve the equation. If you want to try out with my numbers I have $R_i=25, L=250, b=6$ (distance between each spiral).

My final goal is to write an equation in excel that I can change the 3 parameters I gave above and it will give out the number of turns for the spiral.

Thank you!

Comment: It's useful to "stretch out" the spiral into a right triangle. The total length $L$ is the longest side of the triangle. Can you figure out how to calculate the slope of the triangle?

Comment: I dont think I've ever heard of this technique before so probably not

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Length of a Spiral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2825984/length-of-a-spiral)